# Getting only the version of a NuGet package through commandline?

Tags: nuget

I'm trying to fetch the version of a package that I have installed via the NuGet commandline (or a PowerShell command to be more specific).

When I enter the following:

```
Get-Package -Filter Antlr
```

I get the following output:

```
Id                             Version              Description/Release Notes        
--                             -------              -------------------------        
Antlr                          3.4.1.9004           ANother Tool for Language Reco...
```

But this is more than I need. How do I retrieve just the version for "Antlr"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will give you just the version number as a string:

```
Get-Package -Filter Antlr | % { $_.Version.ToString() }
```

If you need the Version as an object then remove the `.ToString()` part.